# option to non-forced update in Android Market

Tags: google-play, updates

I need to make a couple of minor changes to my app - minor bug fixes but mostly new ad-related code.  When I publish this new version to the android market, I'll be changing the versioncode but not the versionname.

But in reality ---  I don't want to bother my current users with an update that's mostly about advertising, especially when we are about to embark on the major marketing and paid download campaign to add a bunch of future users.

So is there a way to publish the update WITHOUT having to notify my current users?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
[Force update android app when new version available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244305/force-update-android-app-when-new-version-available/32942785#32942785), instead of dialog box, update in background and it would always work, tried and tested

Answer (score 0):

No, the notification system is 100% automatic. The only way to block update notifications is by doing it on the client side: `Android market > menu > settings > Notifications` (this will block all update notifications for all applications).