# Force update for the latest version of android app

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to figure out how to **forcefully update the latest version** from play store.

As the older version of my android app is already in play store where i haven't implement the check to get the current version of the app and compare with the play store app version like specified in the link [update android app forcefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244305/force-update-android-app-when-new-version-available)

I want that when I upload my new version on play store then user should not be able to use the app till he `update the new version`.

Could you please help me out.

Comment: This open source GitHub project (MAHAndroidUpdater)is completely providing update functionality. Try it, Very simple. https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater

Answer (score 3):

I have to do the same thing but what i did i gonna share you i hope this will help you.

1> I get the previous code version of my application and store it the string.xml. like my live app version code is 1. And my new app version code is 1.1.

**This code is tell us our app version code.**

```
        PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);  
        int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;  
        String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

2> Than check

```
if (newcodeversion > previouscodeversion) {
```

// open any activity or pop up
         }

3> And in the new activity place Text view with text "you have update version" and a button.And on the click of that button navigate to google play store.

```
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("Your application URL"));
                startActivity(i);
```

Comment: The older version which is on play store does not have this code. Now i am launching new version so i want user to update app forcefully.

Comment: Is your application using  webservices??

Comment: Yes, app is using webservices.

Comment: okay, and your app has admin panel too.So create one webservice which has your new version like 1.1.In my backend they have my app oldversion code.
"https://webservicename?version=" + "1.1" 
And on the response  of that webservice i am check checking the same.

Like :
 if (mJsonObject.getString("update").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                    // update = mJsonObject.getString("update");
                    mendatory = mJsonObject.getString("mendatory");
                    item = mJsonObject.getString("item");
 if (mendatory.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
INtent of new activity
}

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible if the logic of comparing the versionCode and blocking the user isn't already placed inside the current app on PlayStore.

Answer (score 1):

This is not difficult to do. Simply bar the user from having the core functionality of what ever your app is responsible for.

Example, if it is a calling app, do a version check, and if the user has not updated as yet, restrict the use of call making entirely.

According to [@pieter-b](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/51367/pieter-b), taken from [Forcing Updates](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/223252):

> For this to work, some kind of logic the app uses needs to be under your control. And then without that part of logic the app won't work
>   and you can show a message: "your app is out of date, please download
>   the new version to continue use."
>
> Consider a messenger app where traffic goes through your servers. Just
>   refuse to deliver messages of clients using an outdated version.

Also refer to [Force update android app when new version available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244305/force-update-android-app-when-new-version-available).