# Android version code for App updating

Tags: android, version

I read that if we want to update an app in google play, the version Code should be higher than the previous apk file. I've an app with version code: 20 and version name 1.0. So to update the app, how should I increase the version code? Should it increase by 10? or just 1 is enough? ie, version code from 20 to 30 or version code from 20 to 21?

Comment: Increase the version code by 1. Also when you are performing an update increase also the version name from 1.0 to 1.0.1 or 1.1 just for better tracking ..

Comment: Thanks Ran. I'll do it.

Comment: Cool.. glad to help. if can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: I read it before asking here Ran. But had a confusion about how much should i add. Thanks again for clearing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I increased it from code 1 and version 1.0 to code 2 and version 1.1 . That's also what it says in my developer console. So just do as you wish

Answer (score 2):

**[VersionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html)**

> This number is used only to determine whether one version is more
>   recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent
>   versions.  Typically, you would release the first version of your app
>   with versionCode set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with
>   each release, regardless whether the release constitutes a major or
>   minor release. This means that the versionCode value does not
>   necessarily have a strong resemblance to the app release version that
>   is visible to the user (see versionName, below). Apps and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.

```
    defaultConfig 
    {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1  // Default , You can increase 1 when update .
    versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Play Core Library In-app updates to tackle this. You can [check for update availability](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#update_readiness) and [install them](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#start_update) if available seamlessly.

In-app updates are not compatible with apps that use APK expansion files (.obb files). You can either go for [flexible downloads](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#install_flexible) or [immediate updates](https://develo) which Google Play takes care of downloading and installing the update for you.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0'
    ...
}
```

Note that, In-app updates works only with devices running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher, and requires you to use [Play Core library](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#include_playcore) 1.5.0 or higher. 
'

I hope this will help somebody

Answer (score 1):

Basically, For update your apk you should update version code to 21(just 1 increase) and your version name.

Comment: this can be posted as comment, once you have reputations to do it.