# How do I force an expo app to update

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have an app written in expo, and can't figure out how to push a new build. On the expo site if I run the app from the QR code the app is correct, but the native app from the app store doesn't update.

The steps I've been using are 
1) exp build:android
2) exp publish

How do I make the app actually update?

Comment: please upload  appstore to each build .

Comment: My understanding was that expo does OTA updates: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-ota-updates

Comment: Are you creating the builds with the same version of expo?

Answer (score 27):

**TL;DR**: OTA updates are enforced by default. App Store updates can be enforced by adding code to check your app version on startup and, if there's a new version, open the App Store on your app's page.

There's two ways of updating a standalone Expo app:

1. OTA update using `expo-cli publish`
2. Using Google Play/App Store

Both of these methods have advantages and shortcomings.

#### OTA Updates

This is the usual way an update is delivered to Expo apps. OTAs are done via the [expo CLI tool](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/expo-cli/) and deliver new Javascript code based on your `package.json` settings. This option also offers the option to publish code using **release channels**, meaning you could push updates first to you staging environment, validate the update and then push it to production via CLI like so:

```sh
expo-cli publish -release-channel staging # pushes and update to the staging channel
expo-cli publish -release-channel production # pushes an update to the production channel
```

If you are publishing but your standalone app is not updating you might be pushing code to the wrong release channel. You can read more about release channels [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/release-channels/).

OTAs are enforced by default:

> By default, Expo will check for updates automatically when your app is launched and will try to fetch the latest published version. If a new bundle is available, Expo will attempt to download it before launching the experience.

However it's possible to disable this behavior by setting `updates.enabled` to `false` in app.json and then implement your own logic (or none at all), as per the example in their docs:

```js
try {
  const update = await Expo.Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
  if (update.isAvailable) {
    await Expo.Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
    // ... notify user of update ...
    Expo.Updates.reloadFromCache();
  }
} catch (e) {
  // handle or log error
}
```

This system is really great for pushing new JS code to your users, it really helps with live testing since you can test your app with your user, find a flaw, fix it and publish new code which will be almost instantly available for download.

Yet this method has its limitations, for example: you can't update the Expo SDK version this way, you must build a new standalone app and distribute it through the app store (or whatever other method of your choosing).

#### App Stores

This is the most common way to distribute your `.apk` and `.ipa` files. These files can be created by using the `expo-cli build:android` and `expo-cli build:ios` for Android and iOS respectively.

It seems like there's an Android API being tested to enforce apps to be updated via this method ([SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227426/10951917), [article](https://techcrunch.com/2018/11/07/android-developers-can-now-force-users-to-update-their-apps/)), but I don't think it's available yet.

One possible solution to enforce updates via this method is to check your app version on startup and, if there's a new version available in the store, open the app's store page via [deep linking](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/) so the user is able download it. The example below should help you visualize what I mean.

```js
componentDidMount {
   const hasNewVersion = isStoreUpdateAvailable(); // Checks the store for a new app update
   if (hasNewVersion) {
     Linking.openURL("market://details?id=<>"); // Opens the app's store page so the user can download the update
   }
}
```

Here's the docs about [linking to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play).

Hope this answers all your questions, if not leave a comment and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Can this `Linking.openURL("market://details?id=<>");` also send to AppStore from iOS? On my app it's working only on Android

Comment: That's for Android only, yes. I don't know right know how to achieve a similar result on iOS.

Comment: On iOS, you should just open the URL to the app store's website, and it'll deep link properly.

Answer (score 14):

### UPDATED ANSWER

Since the **accepted answer** was posted, Expo made changes to the [Updates API](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/).

Here's the breaking change.

> Updates.reloadFromCache has been renamed to **Updates.reloadAsync**, and Updates.reload has been removed.

```
  import * as Updates from 'expo-updates' // Updates*

  try {
    const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync()
    if (update.isAvailable) {
      await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync()
      // NOTIFY USER HERE
      Updates.reloadAsync()
    }
  } catch (e) {
      // HANDLE ERROR HERE
  }
```

For those wondering where to run this code, I advise to insert it in the componentDidMount/useEffect() method.

Comment: This code is useful for fetching the update and updating the app, but where this update will download and for developer, how to give update to users. Please help me out with this questions.

Comment: Expo handles that for you. When you create a build of your app, it automatically uploads the build to Expo's amazon service (it gives you an URL to check as well). You just need to insert the code above and Expo will update the app OTA (Over The Air).

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for an easy to integrate built in solution. You can use App Upgrade https://appupgrade.dev/ service to force update your mobile apps.

- Create new version entry for your app version that you want to update in the app upgrade service and select whether you want to force it or just want to let users know that new version is available.

[image: App Upgrade]

- Integrate your app with App Upgrade using available SDK. Official SDK are available for React Native, Flutter, Expo, Android and iOS(Swift).
  The SDK will take care of the rest.
  Whenever you want to force upgrade a version just create a version entry in app upgrade dashboard.

[image: App Upgrade Popup]

- You can also integrate using API. Just call the appupgrade api from your app with the required details such as your app version, platform, environment and app name.
- The API will return you the details.. that this app needs to be updated or not.
- Based on the response you can show popup in your app.You can call this API when app starts or periodically to check for the update. You can even provide a custom message.
  API response:

[image: App Upgrade API Response]

See the response has force update true. So handle in the app by showing popup.

[image: App Upgrade Popup]

You can find the complete user documentation here. https://appupgrade.dev/docs

Thanks.