# Update Apk automatically on update found from google play

Tags: android, apk, auto-update

I want to implement auto update on my android app, but i don`t know how to do it. Can you please help me, I have searched the web but i cant find it.

I have tired ,

The code in 
[Force update android app when new version available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244305/force-update-android-app-when-new-version-available). 
But it didn't work at all.

Comment: Check this link carefully it's working answers..

Comment: dude it woks ya know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys I have found the answer I am currently using javiersantos AppUpdater