# Is there a way to force update in android whitout consuming a webservice? For example, directly with playstore deploy options?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application deployed on the play store. I need to do a critical update for all the customers but in the current version, I haven't implemented a private Webservice to do version control. Is there a way do force mass update, turning the previous version obsolete only utilizing resources of the Cordova/ionic/android/playstore environment?

My searches only pinpointed to create a Webservice consumption, like these: [Force update of an Android app when a new version is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244305/force-update-of-an-android-app-when-a-new-version-is-available), but my current version spread to more than 5 thousand customers don't have this resource yet.

I need a way to do it in my actual environment and I'll do love to receive suggestions of how to accomplish that with the minimum interactivity of the customers, to assure the fastest spread possible.

Comment: I don't believe you can force it. What makes it critical?

Comment: There is a cordova plugin for `code push`, which updates your application without playstore requirement. check: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/code-push
think its paid.

Comment: @Stefan security issues.

Comment: @Najamussaqib thanks for the example. But there are a way to do it without the need to modify the application? Like configure play store to automatically mark the version obsolete, turning the old version inaccessible for the customer, and suggesting to update?

Comment: Playstore handle this automatically, if the update available playstore shows notification of update available. but you can force it through platystore. You can implement in inside your application via web-service. and check if updated availbale you can lock you application by yourself.