# upgrade Native mobile app to flutter with forceful

Tags: android, ios, flutter

We have already developed native mobile app for both platfroms like Android and iOS a few years ago, now we developed Flutter mobile app both platfroms.

I want replace flutter app instead of native mobile app.

I understand few steps like below:

```
1. we can use same application ID
2. we can use same account as well as KEYS.

But, How to notify existing app users for latest update?
```

can any one help us to understand how we can achive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is self explanatory. You have already know the solution.

In the reply of your first point

> 1. we can use same application ID

In your flutter application, navigate to android project's app level build and update the flutter app **Application ID** with your existing application id. (My be you already know it).

Mobile OS installs the app based on Application ID, So you can not install multiple apps with the unique ID.

Now lets come to the second point

> 2. we can use same account as well as KEYS.

When you will generate the flutter app (android/ios) with the existing keys. Lets say your existing app on google play console is built with xyz.jks. Built your flutter android project with same key and publish on google play store.

> But, How to notify existing app users for latest update?

If you built your flutter android apk with the same key (xyz.jks), you don't have to worry about the update notification, google play store will handle it and notify the users that an update is avaiable.

But if your end users disabled the app update notification, he will not be notified. In addition to it, if you change your key (xyz.jks) to build the release apk, all your existing users will not be notified.

**Tip:** if you have integrated firebase in your apps, then you can send update notification from FCM to the users that an update is available.

**Note:** I never published iOS app so I don't have info about app store so far.

Comment: So you mean to say, Play Store will take care notfiy the user updates?

Comment: yes it will, only if you generate build by using the same key files

Comment: Thank you so much, someone already developed and maintain by native apps. now we are developed new app using flutter, need to undestand how replace existing app with my flutter app and should notfiy the users. what kind of questions should i ask them? if google play store will automatically send notifications but user does not updated what should we do, how to maintain forceful update users. could you please help me...

Comment: ok to force the user to update, your published app should have the code to force the users to update. play store does not have option in play console.

Comment: code should done by native app not into flutter right ?

Comment: Not necessary. your app should have the logic to force the user. check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244305/force-update-of-an-android-app-when-a-new-version-is-available
I meant, your published app should have the logic of force update. If you published app does not the logic, then you cannot force the user. 
Read it too https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates. 
Again it should be in published app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225163/discussion-between-coder-and-faiizii-awan).

Answer (score 0):

Q: How to notify existing app users for latest update?

A: Just Update the version (example V 2.0.1) and release the apk/aap and iOS under respective account of Play Store and App Store of the same app. The users will automatically get notified from play store app on their mobile that an update is available for your app.

Comment: I need foreful update means mandtrory update becuase almost entier app is changed native mobile app to flutter mobile app. so user should update mandatroy not optional, how can we do that ?

Comment: You can also use your own server and enable your app to read the current version from there (If your native app has server feature). If your native app has notification feature then you can push a notification to all active users informing about update. Further If your native application does some calls to an API that you manage, you can include the app version in each call and return a special error code to the application if the version is outdated. ```https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader``` Introduce this feature in this version of your app.

Comment: Normally mobiles will have the feature of automatic update on Wi-Fi and on particular time.. So It will get updated don't worry.